# Accuracy of Rosenbrock's test function calculation

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I want to calculate Rosenbrock's test function

[image]

I have implemented the following C/C++ code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N = 900000;

    float *x = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) x[i] = 3.f;

    float sum_host = 0.f;
    for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
        float temp = (100.f * (x[i+1] - x[i] * x[i]) * (x[i+1] - x[i] * x[i]) + (x[i] - 1.f) * (x[i] - 1.f));
        sum_host = sum_host + temp;
        printf("%i %f %f\n", i, temp, sum_host);
    }
    printf("Result for Rosenbrock's test function calculation = %f\n", sum_host);

}
```

Since the `x` array is initialized to `3.f`, then each summation term should be `3604.f`, so that the final summation involving `899999` terms should be `3243596396`. However, the result I get is `3229239296`, with an absolute error of `14357100`. If I measure the difference between two consecutive partial summations, I see that it is `3600.f` for the early partial summations and then it drops to `3584` for the last ones, while it should always be `3604.f`.

If I use Kahan summation algorithm as

```
sum_host = 0.f;
float c        = 0.f;
for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
    float temp = (100.f * (x[i+1] - x[i] * x[i]) * (x[i+1] - x[i] * x[i]) + (x[i] - 1.f) * (x[i] - 1.f)) - c;
    float t    = sum_host + temp;
    c          = (t - sum_host) - temp;
    sum_host = t;
}
```

the result I get is `3243596288`, with a much smaller absolute error of `108`.

I'm pretty sure that this effect I see should be ascribed to the precision of floating point arithmetics. Could someone confirm this and provide me an explanation of the mechanism according to which this occurs?

Comment: It starts at 3604 for me, rather than 3600.  Did you make a typo?

Comment: @tmyklebu That value (`3600`) does not refer to the very first finite difference between consecutive partial summations, but to (about) the `26000`th difference.

Comment: @chux That is indeed a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @JackOLantern The solution to this problem, in case you missed it in Chux's answer is to replace every instance of the word `float` with the word `double`, and fix the constants as well, e.g. `3.f` becomes `3.0`. The calculation that you're doing won't exceed the precision of a `double`, and hence the results of the calculation will have 0 error.

Comment: @user3386109 Agree with the  suggestion about changing `float` to `double` except that the array `*x` may remain `float` for space considerations.  Simple way to make `x[i] * x[i]` work at `double` is to do `1.0 * x[i] * x[i]` or `(double) x[i] * x[i]`.

Comment: @chux To quote some anonymous wise guy, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Which is to say that you shouldn't optimize for space unless space is actually a problem. Personally, I've never worked with a computer that could store 900000 floats, but couldn't just as easily store 900000 doubles. (In the good old days, I did work with PCs that couldn't store 900000 doubles, but they couldn't store 900000 floats either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compute `temp = 3604.0f` accurately at each iteration.  The problem arises when you try adding `3604.0f` to something else and round the result to the nearest `float`.  `float`s store an exponent and a 23-bit significand, meaning any result with 1-bits more than 24 places apart is going to get rounded to something other than what it is.

Note that 3604 = 901 * 4 and the binary expansion of 901 is 1110000101; you'll start seeing roundoff once you start adding `temp` to something bigger than 2^24 * 4 = 67108864.  (This happens when you run the code, too; it starts printing out 3600 as the difference between consecutive sum_host's right when sum_host exceeds 67108864.)  You start seeing even more roundoff when you're adding `temp` to something bigger than 2^26 * 4; at that point, the second smallest '1' bit is getting swallowed as well.

Note that, after you do Kahan summation, `sum_host` is what you report AND `c` is `-108`.  This is loosely because `c` is keeping track of the next most significant 24 bits.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Uh-oh.  Is it impossibly hard, perchance?

Comment: BTW: [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has 24-bit binary significand (23 bits stored explicitly))

Answer (score 2):

Typical `float` is only good to maybe 7 digits of precision.   Repeatedly adding `3604` to a number 100000x larger than it does not well accumulate the lesser significant digits.

Use `double`.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think your answer addresses the question to any depth.  Downvotes are reversible; if you improve your answer, I'm happy to turn the downvote into an upvote.

Comment: @tmyklebu I posted, you posted 10 seconds later, you down voted 3 seconds later.  Hmmm.  This answer is terse and correct.  It goes into enough depth to explain the issue and offers a solution.